# CSS Multiple Colum Alignment

Tags: css, alignment, positioning, styling

http://jsfiddle.net/auyUS/8/

The only problem I'm having atm is the css positioning, and alignment. I think it'll be easier using lists (ul, li) instead of paragraphs for displaying the contractors when they punch in, and out.

I want the punch in button, textbox, and punch out buttons remain on the bottom of the page at 0px and width filling up the page (via the textbox of course), regardless of resolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your **#container div** declaration like this:

```
#container div {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

Replaced display:inline with float:left and backed of the width a little bit.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/GpJKc/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, try changing your `#container div` in your css to this:

```
#container div {
float:left;
width:30%;}
```